# Python program uses takes up a lot of memory storage per iteration

Tags: python

I created a program that I'm distributing. The program checks for username availability, and after each check a variable named `checkedCount` gets updated. Each check costs about 4mb or ram, which makes the total memory usage high. For example, I ran the program for about two hours which resulted in 7gb's of ram being in use. I've tried to use `clear = lambda: os.system('cls')` after each request to clear the terminal, but that didn't work.

Code:

```
    def screen(self):
        clear()
        print(r"""
 /~\
C oo
_( ^)
/   ~\
""")
        print(f"""{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[>]{Fore.RESET} Checks: {self.checkedCount}        
{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[>]{Fore.RESET} Claims: {self.claimedCount}       
{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[>]{Fore.RESET} Errors: {self.errorCount}      
            """)


    def checker(self):
        self.proxer = self.proxies()
        while True:
            self.screen()
            [self.usernames.put(line.strip()) for line in open(f"external/{wordlistInput}")]  
            name = self.usernames.get(); self.usernames.put(name)
            url = f"https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?nameOnPlatform={name}&platformType=uplay"   
            if len(name) > 2:
                try:
                    r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers, proxies=self.proxer)
                    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')} | Developed by gxzs#2979")

                    if self.checkedCount % 75 == 0:
                        self.checkedCount += 1
                        self.proxer = self.proxies()
                        self.login()
 
                    if r.status_code == 200:
                        self.checkedCount += 1
                        if len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0:    
                            pass    
                        else:  
                            self.create(name)
                    else:
                        with open('external/errors.txt', "a") as errorFile:
                            errorFile.write(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')} | Error message: {r.text}\n")
                        self.errorCount += 1
                        self.proxer = self.proxies()
                        self.login()
             
                except Exception:
                    pass
```

Edit:                                  It doesn't seem to be a issue with the variable checkedCount. I removed it from the code and it still happens
[image]

Comment: Well, we need a Minimal Reproducible Example, or at least some code at all, to be able to help you.

Comment: @Programmer Added a part of the code

Comment: Some ideas on [how to profile memory usage in Python](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-profile-memory-usage-in-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what kind of data struture is `self.username` and if the `.put()` method overwrites already existing entries, but if it doesn't then
the line:

`[self.usernames.put(line.strip()) for line in open(f"external/{wordlistInput}")]`

Will put the content of `f"external/{wordlistInput}"` at every iteration in your `while True:` inside `self.usernames` without ever clearing it's content.

Also you are not exiting the `while`, I don't know if its intentional.

This is a shot in the dark since there isn't more information available.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it now doesnt eat my ram! I changed the read statement to `for line in open(f'external/{wordlistInput}', 'r'):` and put this above the `while` loop. Sorry for adding a limited amount of information.